# Flutter app size is doubled after flutter pub upgrade, Initial apk is almost 37mb and now the apk size is about 75mb after pub upgrade

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-apk

The image mentioned by running the command  "flutter build apk --analyze-size --target-platform android-arm64" apk analyze-size ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FqNW.png)

How to reduce the size of the apk to the older size as mentioned;
Note: I have run pub clean, pub get, cache repair etc.

Comment: It could be that one of the plugins you depend on got a lot bigger. Typically a large increase like that is due to an image or some other asset being added by you or one of your dependencies.

Comment: arm64-v8a is about 19mb